# Type conversion from FORTRAN to C#

Tags: c#, fortran

I have in F2008

```
module mod_Blood
use mod_liquid
implicit none
type, public :: typ_BloodComponents
    character(len=5) :: name
    real(DP):: salt
    real(DP):: RBC
end type typ_BloodComponents

type, public :: typ_BloodWork
    real(DP) :: DrugConc
    real(DP) :: Dilution
    real(DP) :: volume  
    type(typ_BloodComponents) :: vein, artery

    contains
          procedure :: SetParameters => blood_SetParameters
          procedure :: BloodProteinParams  => blood_BloodProteinParams   
end type typ_BloodWork
end mod_Blood
```

I know that vein and artery both have variables vein%name, vein%salt, vein%RBC and artery%name, artery%salt and artery%RBC.

How can I transfer this over to C#?  Is a module a namespace?  And is a FORTRAN "type" a class in C#?

Would it make sense if I did something like:

```
class BloodComponents
{
string name;
double salt;
double RBC;
}

class BloodWork
{
    double drugConc
    double dil
    double volume

    class Vein : BloodComponents
    {}
    class Artery : BloodComponents
    {}

    void SetParameters()
    {...}
    void BloodComponentParameter()
    {...}
}
```

Or have I interpreted the FORTRAN wrong?

Comment: "is a FORTRAN "type" a class in C#?" > I'm not able to go into much detail in comparing both, but from what I see, it seems that a Fortran type could indeed be translated as a C# class. And your implementation seems ok, or at least logic.

Comment: unless you're having specific issues with your c# version this may be a better fit for [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: then what would a module be?  I can define directly in a FORTEAN module, but cannot do the same with a namespace in C#.

Comment: What is the definition of `SetParameters` and `BloodProteinParams`?

Comment: @BBH1023: a module in Fortran is akin to a namespace (and perhaps sometimes a class). Data structures in these two languages may overlap, but they're not 1:1. Do not work on directly porting, but instead port the intent. If you need a class use a class, who cares if the Fortran used `module` or `common`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
namespace Blood
{
    public struct BloodComponents
    {
        public string name;
        public double salt, RBC;
    }

    public struct BloodWork
    {
        public double drugConc, dilution, volume;
        public BloodComponents vein, artery;

        public void SetParameters()
        {
        }
        public void BloodProteintParams()
        {
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var work=new BloodWork()
            {
                drugConc=0.1,
                dilution=0.2,
                volume=0.3,
                vein=new BloodComponents() { name="A", RBC=0.2, salt=0.6 },
                artery=new BloodComponents() { name="B", RBC=0.5, salt=0.9 }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Everything is a `struct` so values are copied only. If you want to reference the same instant of `BloodWork` for example in multiple places then you need to change the type to `class`.

Comment: It would be best to avoid `struct` in C# and use `class` instead, even if `struct` is closer to the semantics of Fortran.

Comment: @sixlettervariables Why? References?

Comment: Because they do not work like people think they do. If you can change the value of any of the members of your struct, you will likely run into problems. Structs should be the exception to the rule, typically for P/Invoke or when you *really* need copy semantics.

Comment: Their intended use is to hold values which they do very well and efficiently. No problems if you know what you are doing. I think creating references causes problems when people expect copies. The corollary works against your case, so it is just an opinion.